# How can I re-establish a NFC-connection programmatically WITHOUT removing the device? (react-native-nfc-manager)

Tags: android, react-native, nfc, react-native-nfc-manager

I use react-native-nfc-manager (3.10.1) in an react-native application (0.62.2) and a Mifare Ultralight NFC technology on an Android device.

How can I re-establish a NFC-connection programmatically WITHOUT removing the device?

The sequence is like this:

1. Approaching the device to NFC creates an NFC connection
2. App reads NFC content
3. App writes a request header to NFC
4. App app cancels NFC connection and creates a waiting time

- case a:  Device removed and approached again: App can create new connection and can move to next step -> fine
- *case b: Device not removed: App should create new connection to be able to read in next step -> app can't establish new NFC connection*

5. App reads NFC content

This is the minimum code I am using:

```
    // Initialising NFC Manager
    await NfcManager.start();

    // 1.
    // Request Technology
    await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.MifareUltralight);

    // Get NFC Tag information
    const nfcTag = await NfcManager.getTag();

    // 2.
    // Read Mifare pages
    const pages = await NfcManager.mifareUltralightHandlerAndroid.mifareUltralightReadPages(pageOffset)

    // 3.
    // Write Mifare data
    await NfcManager.mifareUltralightHandlerAndroid.mifareUltralightWritePage(pageOffset, data);

    // 4.b.
    // Cancel NFC Connection programmatically without removing device
    NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest();
    // This step is important, because with not canceling the other device can't access the NFC-Chip to write. If I would not need this step, my desired flow would work.

    // Wait for other device writing to NFC-chip (via wire, not through NFC connection)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTime));

    // Device should not be removed during waiting in this case
 
    // Request Technology
    await NfcManager.requestTechnology(NfcTech.MifareUltralight);
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK, it keeps on waiting. If I remove the device and approach it again it works

    // 5.
    // Read Mifare pages
    const pages = await NfcManager.mifareUltralightHandlerAndroid.mifareUltralightReadPages(pageOffset)
```

Background to this task is, that I want to write a request header, wait for the counterpart to write the content and after a waiting time to read that content, and all steps without removing the device from the NFC-Chip.

This is the used NFC Chip and it's states diagram:

[image: NFC Chip state machine]

Comment: Hey!! do you're able to get the 'NDEF' values from the NFC card if you did then please can you help me? @vindom

Comment: I am handling a Chip with a Mifare technology, not NDEF @varun